# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, I understand that there are billion of question on this error, but this error have been killing me for couple of hours allready. Please if someone could point out my mistake!

index.html:

```
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.4.1/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="jigup">
        <div data-ui-view=""></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.module.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.config.js'); ?>"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/mapComponent/map.module.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/mapComponent/map.component.js'); ?>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.module.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('jigup', [
        'ui.router',
        'map',
        //'ngMap'
    ]);
})();
```

app.config.js:

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module('jigup')
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/map");
            $stateProvider
                .state("map", {
                    url: "/map",
                    component: "mapComponent"
                })
                .state("map.about", {
                    url: "/about",
                    templateUrl: "about.html"
                })
        });     
})();
```

mapComponent/map.module.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('map', [
        'ngMap'
    ]);
})();
```

mapComponent/map.component.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('map')
        .component('mapComponent', {
            template: 'this is map',
            /* controller: mapController */
        });

    /* mapController.$inject = ['ngMap'];
    function mapController(ngMap){

    } */
})();
```

I have checked that every file succesfully downloads but always(did not ge if commented out `'map'` from `app.module.js`) get error:

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=jigup&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4630
    at q (angular.js:322)
    at g (angular.js:4591)
    at db (angular.js:4513)
    at c (angular.js:1777)
    at Ac (angular.js:1798)
    at fe (angular.js:1683)
    at angular.js:31018
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3197)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sequence of files. The `jigup` module is dependent on `map` modoule, so that should be defined earlier.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/mapComponent/map.module.js'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.module.js'); ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/app.config.js'); ?>"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('app/mapComponent/map.component.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: This did not change anything. however if uncommenting 'ngMap' error disappears, so the problem actually is with ngMap